# Can't gzip my mysqldump on the command line windows

Tags: command-line, mysql, sqlcommand

I'm trying to make a back up of my MySQL db and zip the file.

Every time I try to run this command...

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysqldump.exe -u usernam -ppassword db_name | gzip > sites\www.site.com-local\backups\backup-date.sql.gz
```

All I get is an error saying "'gzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'

I've used the following resources hoping they would help but have done nothing

http://www.zigpress.com/2009/04/09/enabling-gzip-on-wamp/
http://dnhome.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/apache-wampserver-enable-compression-gzip/
http://www.dewebbouwmeester.nl/enabling-gzip-on-wamp/

All say the same thing but nothing happens.

Could someone please shine some light on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this same problem myself with WAMP.

All you need to do is:

1. Download gzip.exe from here: http://www.gzip.org/#exe
2. Place gzip.exe in your PHP folder

Answer (score 0):

That is telling you that gzip is nowhere your system can find. You can blame however you installed gzip.

Check the value of your $PATH environment (or system) variable. Then install a copy of gzip in one of those directories.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to put `zip.exe` in your wamp folder, like `wamp/bin/mysql/[your mysql version]/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Find or install gzip locally. After that directly in `PHP` folder create just `gzip.bat` file, specify the fully qualified path to existing gzip binary file and save.
For example:`C:\git\bin\gzip.exe`

It's not necessary to place `gzip.exe` in your `PHP` folder.